# Write a robust timer in linux

Tags: c, linux, timer

I want to implement a robust timer for an embedded linux application. The goal of this is to control over functions's time of execution and if they take too long, generate an interruption to stop the function's loop.

I searched all over the internet and the firs proposition was to use `clock()` function.

The solution with `clock()` function could be :

```C
#include <time.h>

int func(void){

  //the starting time of the function
  clock_t initial_time;
  clock_t elapsed_time;

  initial_time = clock()*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

  do{
    //some stuff
    elapsed_time = clock()*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC - initial_time;
  }while(elapsed_time < timeout_ms);

  printf("time to get command : %ld\n", elapsed_time);

  //send an error if a timeout was reached
  if(elapsed_time >= timeout_ms){
    return -1;
  }
  else{
    return 1;
  }
}
```

But this is not really robust as clock() could cause an overflow in between the function calculations and so, elapsed time will go negative and it will never get out of the loop. **This was corrected in the edit section bellow**

Second solution was to use the linux kernel timers as following :

```C
#include <linux/module.h> /* Needed by all modules */
#include <linux/kernel.h> /* Needed for KERN_INFO */
#include <linux/init.h> /* Needed for the macros */
#include <linux/timer.h>
 
int g_time_interval = 10000;
struct timer_list g_timer;

void timer_handler (unsigned long data)
{
     // do your timer stuff here
}

int init_timer(void)
{ 
    setup_timer(&g_timer, timer_handler, 0);
    mod_timer( &g_timer, jiffies + msecs_to_jiffies(g_time_interval));
 
    return 0;
}
 
void close_timer(void)
{
    del_timer(&g_timer);
}
```

This option seems ok, but I did some research and jiffies (the number of ticks since startup) could overflow too and I don't know if this could affect my usage of this timer. **This was corrected in the edit section bellow**

Finally, the last option I found was to use timer_create with a signal. As far as I know, this does not has the overflow issue if used with CLOCK_MONOTONIC :

```C
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define SIG SIG_RTMIN

int init_timer((void *) handler(int, siginfo_t, void*)){

  // Establish handler for timer signal
  sa.sa_flags = SA_SIGINFO;
  sa.sa_sigaction = handler;
  sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
  if (sigaction(SIG, &sa, NULL) == -1)
      printf("Error initializing timer\n");

  // Block timer signal temporarily
  printf("Blocking signal %d\n", SIG);
  sigemptyset(&mask);
  sigaddset(&mask, SIG);

  // Create the timer
  sev.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
  sev.sigev_signo = SIG;
  sev.sigev_value.sival_ptr = &timerid;
}

static void handler(int sig, siginfo_t *si, void *uc)
{
    //put a flag to 1 for example
    signal(sig, SIG_IGN);
}
//Much other stuff ...
```

But google told me that we can only set one handler per signal and I dont know if the other processus that are in my linux board use SIG_RTMIN. And as I do not want to break everything by redefining its handler, it is not a convinient solution.

Am I getting something wrong here?
Is there a way to define a timer in linux without having this issues?

Thank you very much to all :)

## Edit

Overflow will not cause an issue so option 1 and 2 are valid. **Now which one would be the most robust?**

Here is the explanation on why I was wrong about overflow. Giving the case where we want to calculate elapsed_time and the maximum clock value is MAX. We have as above :

```C
elapsed_time = clock()*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC - initial_time;
```

Lets rename `clock()*1000/CLOCKS_PER_SEC` as x. If there is overflow, then theorically `theoric_x > MAX`, but as there was overflow, `x = theoric_x - MAX` (hope is clear ':D). So :

```C
elapsed_time = (theoric_x - MAX) - initial_time;
```

Which can be written as :

```C
elapsed_time = (theoric_x - initial_time) - MAX;
```

And this is equivalent to : `elapsed_time = (theoric_x - initial_time)` because substracting the maximum value is like getting back to the same value (it works like modulo). This is ok while the `theoric_x` is below `initial_time + MAX`, if we get over, the elapsed time will reset.

I hope it was clear enough.

Comment: subtracting two unsigned values will not give the wrong result even when the second one has overflowed.

Comment: POSIX defines `clock_gettime`, why not use that?

Comment: You are right @stark. Still, I would like to know which is the cleanest way to implement the timer. Is it with the linux kernel or with clock() function?

Comment: Depends on whether you want elapsed wall-clock time, or just your process run time.

Comment: I think process runtime is ok. My goal is not really to be precise (I can accept a 50% error margin over the elapsed time) but to be robust. To be sure that in any circumstances (parrallel process running, other threads ...) my process won't get stuck in a loop forever.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But google told me that we can only set one handler per signal and I dont know if the other processus that are in my linux board use SIG_RTMIN.

No, it is *one handler per signal* **per process**.

That is, having a signal handler for SIGRTMIN in your own program will not interfere with SIGRTMIN handlers of any other processes.  Similarly, creating a timer will not affect any other processes' timers either.  All you need to worry about, is your own process.

(Technically, there are only a limited number of timers available, so you don't want to create hundreds of them in a single process.)

If you have only one thread in the process, consider the following timeout scheme:

```c
// SPDX-License-Identifier: CC0-1.0

#define  _POSIX_C_SOURCE  200809L
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define   TIMEOUT_SIGNAL     (SIGRTMIN+0)
#define   TIMEOUT_REPEAT_NS  1000000        /* Repeat every millisecond until canceled */

static volatile sig_atomic_t  timeout_elapsed;  /* Nonzero if timeout has elapsed */
static timer_t                timeout_timer;

static void timeout_handler(int signum)
{
    (void)signum; /* Silences warning about unused parameter; generates no code. */
    timeout_elapsed = 1;
}

static int timeout_init(void)
{
    struct sigaction   act;
    struct sigevent    evt;

    memset(&act, 0, sizeof act);
    sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
    act.sa_handler = timeout_handler;
    act.sa_flags = 0;
    if (sigaction(TIMEOUT_SIGNAL, &act, NULL) == -1)
        return errno;

    memset(&evt, 0, sizeof evt);
    evt.sigev_notify = SIGEV_SIGNAL;
    evt.sigev_signo = TIMEOUT_SIGNAL;
    evt.sigev_value.sival_ptr = (void *)0;
    if (timer_create(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, &evt, &timeout_timer) == -1)
        return errno;

    timeout_elapsed = 0;

    return 0;
}

static void timeout_cancel(void)
{
    struct itimerspec  zero;

    zero.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
    zero.it_value.tv_nsec = 0;
    zero.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    zero.it_interval.tv_nsec = 0;

    timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &zero, NULL);
}

static void timeout_set(double seconds)
{
    struct itimerspec  when;
    sigset_t           mask;

    /* Block the timeout signal for now. */
    sigemptyset(&mask);
    sigaddset(&mask, TIMEOUT_SIGNAL);
    sigprocmask(SIG_BLOCK, &mask, NULL);

    /* Make sure any previous timeouts have been canceled. */
    timeout_cancel();

    /* Calculate the next (relative) timeout. */
    if (seconds >= 0.000000001) {
        long  sec = (long)seconds;
        long  nsec = (long)(1000000000.0*(seconds - (double)sec));

        if (nsec < 0)
            nsec = 0;

        if (nsec > 999999999) {
            nsec = 0;
            sec++;
        }

        when.it_value.tv_sec = sec;
        when.it_value.tv_nsec = nsec;
    } else {
        when.it_value.tv_sec = 0;
        when.it_value.tv_nsec = 1;
    }

    /* Set it to repeat, so that it is not easily missed. */
    when.it_interval.tv_sec = 0;
    when.it_interval.tv_nsec = TIMEOUT_REPEAT_NS;

    /* Update the timer. */
    timer_settime(timeout_timer, 0, &when, NULL);

    /* Clear the flag, and unblock the signal. */
    timeout_elapsed = 0;
    sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, &mask, NULL);
}

int main(void)
{
    char   *line_ptr = NULL;
    size_t  line_max = 0;
    ssize_t line_len;

    if (timeout_init()) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Cannot set up timeouts: %s.\n", strerror(errno));
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }

    timeout_set(5.0);
    printf("Please type input lines.  This will timeout in five seconds.\n");
    fflush(stdout);

    while (!timeout_elapsed) {
        line_len = getline(&line_ptr, &line_max, stdin);
        if (line_len > 0) {
            /* Remove trailing newlines */
            line_ptr[strcspn(line_ptr, "\r\n")] = '\0';
            printf("Read %zd bytes: \"%s\".\n", line_len, line_ptr);
            fflush(stdout);
        }
    }

    timeout_cancel();

    free(line_ptr);
    line_ptr = NULL;
    line_max = 0;

    printf("Done.\n");
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Compile using `gcc -Wall -Wextra -O2 example1.c -lrt -o example1` and run `./example1`.

For a multithreaded process, the signal must be delivered to a specific thread, almost always the thread that sets the timeout in the first place.  Here, I recommend a different approach: use a helper thread, a list or an array or a binary min-heap of CLOCK_REALTIME absolute times of the respective timeouts, waiting in [pthread_cond_timedwait()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_cond_wait.3p.html) for the next soonest timeout, or for a signal on the condition variable indicating the timeout list/array/heap has been updated.

Answer (score 0):

POSIX defines [`clock_gettime`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/clock_getres.html). Linux also has [extensions for it](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clock_gettime.2.html).

> The functions `clock_gettime()` and `clock_settime()` retrieve and set the time of the specified clock *clockid*.

You can simply do the following:

```c
#include <time.h>

struct timespec start, end;
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &start);
// Your code here...
clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &end);
```

Then `end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec` will provide you nanoseconds with the resolution as specified by `clock_getres`. Sometimes this is just microseconds or even mere milliseconds. Make sure to check the value and adjust accordingly.

```c
struct timespec res;
clock_getres(CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &res);
switch (res.tv_nsec) {
    case 1000: // microseconds
    case 10000000: // milliseconds
    // cases ...
}
```

### EDIT:

Rereading the original person's post I realize that this doesn't quite answer it. Still, I am leaving it here as it might be useful if applied to the problem. You are free to downvote this if you like as to allow actual answers to rise to the top.